# Adding multiple coredata views

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I have an app with coredata working based on Tim Roadlys Tutorial. The app uses tab bars, with one loading coredata. I have another tab that loads a `UIView` which I am then linking by a button to another `tableView` which will also have coredata.

The problem is the second view crashes when you click the button. Do I pass the managed object context via the segue or do I have to put it in the `appdelegate`?

Thanks for any help :)

Here is the segue

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{


    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Load Ancients Segue"]) {
        UITabBarController *tabBarViewController = (UITabBarController *) [segue destinationViewController];
        AncientsInventoryTVC *ancientsInventoryTVC = (AncientsInventoryTVC *) [[[tabBarViewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:5] topViewController];
        ancientsInventoryTVC.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

}

}
```

When I click the button to load the view I get an error when loading the following; 
 which is what I thought I was fixing with the segue.
self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                        managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                          sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                   cacheName:nil];

Error is - An instance of `NSFetchedResultsController` requires a non-nil `fetchRequest` and `managedObjectContext`

Comment: I worked it out - thanks SO much for everyones help. In the end it was this -

' -(void) viewDidLoad {
    
    id TribezGuidAppDelegate = (id)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.managedObjectContext = [TribezGuidAppDelegate managedObjectContext];
    
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
}'

Answer (score 0):

That's not a lot of info and zero code, but I woul put it in the prepareForSegue call

Comment: `Thanks - I wanted to try the code myself, but while it looks ok in Xcode and loads, I get an error still.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a separate singleton class where you would keep your MOC and use that from both controllers instead of creating MOCs in controllers?

Comment: I'm just looking into doing that and it seems that it is a discouraged practice, any thoughts?

Comment: I'm typically doing things this way for the main MOC. If you're threading for updates, make sure to create MOCs inside the thread and then sync back to main via notifications. Works like a charm.

Comment: I'm sorry but that went completely over my head <see stunned look> I'm still new to CoreData and finding it very confusing

Comment: LOL. You'll cross that bridge when you do the updates in the background. Don't worry about it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface DataServer : NSObject

   +(DataServer *) get;

   @property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
   @property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
   @property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator      *persistentStoreCoordinator;

@end



@implementation DataServer

@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = __managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = __persistentStoreCoordinator;

DataServer * _appData;

+(DataServer *) get {
    if (_appData == nil) {
    _appData = [[DataServer alloc] init];
}
return _appData;
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (__managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return __managedObjectContext;
    } 

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        __managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [__managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    [__managedObjectContext setMergePolicy: NSOverwriteMergePolicy];
    }
    return __managedObjectContext;
}

- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (__managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return __managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"DataModel" withExtension:@"momd"];
    __managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return __managedObjectModel;
} 

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{

    if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSString * dbName = @"MyDbName.sqlite";
    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] 
    URLByAppendingPathComponent: dbName];

    NSError *error = nil;
    __persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] 
    initWithManagedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel];

     // request automatic migration
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
    [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];
    if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator 
        addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType 
        configuration:nil URL:storeURL options: options error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        [[[UIAlertView alloc ]
            initWithTitle: @"Internal Error" 
            message: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", [error userInfo]]
            delegate:nil 
            cancelButtonTitle: @"OK" 
            otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
      }    

       return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }


- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] 
    URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory 
    inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] 
    lastObject];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your help but now I am getting errors all through the singleton about forward declarations. I'm beginning to think it is all beyond me. I don't understand how I have one view controller with the original code working fine and not the second with the same code.